# How quickly could we reach 1 Trillion people?

Tags: population, utopia, future

Ok, first let me explain who I mean by "we".  The human race is currently at 7 billion people, but we are plagued by war, disease and many other things that hold us back and disrupt our population growth.

So consider that "we" exist in a Utopian society, no wars and no disease.  A result of this Utopian society is that our technology has advanced considerably, improving healthcare and life expectancy (which averages around 100 years). Nobody is born with disabilities, there are zero cot-deaths, miscarriages or similar issues.  Everyone is born healthy and is guaranteed to have a long, healthy life until they are roughly a century old.

Our advanced technology also gives us the means with which we can travel the immense distances of space and colonize other worlds.  We have some form of FTL, so the travel time to these new worlds is measured in days or weeks.  The worlds we colonize are effectively identical to Earth, and none of these worlds pose a threat to our survival (in terms of hostile native life or similar threats).  This gives us all the land we need to support a population of 1 trillion.  New worlds can only be colonized by a minimum of roughly 10,000 people.  To keep administration simple, we can only colonize X worlds at one time, where X is the number of worlds that have at least 5 billion people living on them (so to start with we can only colonize 1 world, but once we have colonized that one, we can then colonize 2 worlds, and then after that 4 world and so on).

In this Utopian society, population growth rates are effectively governed by available space. The population on a world will no longer grow when it reaches 10 billion people (eg 2ish children per couple - whatever required to maintain the population but not exceed it).  However a newly colonized world will frequently have birth rates within the 5-10 range - and this birth rate will slowly dwindle until the world has 10 billion people, at which point the population is fairly self sustaining.

Given these "perfect" conditions, and ignoring any possible interference from aliens or events that destroy entire worlds, how long would it take for 7 billion people to reach 1 trillion people.

---

By request, some additional details:

Consider this Utopian society to be very similar to a developed nation here on Earth for all concerns other than what I have described above; So similar gestation times, similar puberty ages etc.

Roughly a 50/50% male to female split for the population.  People in this Utopian society wait until they are in their mid 20s before having kids, and consider a roughly 1-2% of people die from unnatural causes (inc suicides and accidents) and roughly 5% of people decide not to have any children.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95079/discussion-on-question-by-jimmery-how-quickly-could-we-reach-1-trillion-people).

Comment: For future reference: please don't mark an answer as "accepted" within the first few days of receiving an answer.  This is bad form and serves only to dissuade others from writing potentially better answers.

Comment: @elemtilas I don't know if you've noticed, but this question is put on hold - the given answer gave me the kind of answer I was looking for - what would be the point in waiting a few days to mark it as correct when nobody else can submit an answer anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the context of your question, I'll assume by birth-rate you really mean number of viable descendants per person per generation.

A female generation averages at 25.5yrs (the average age that a mother gives birth).  Using a compounding interest calculator, I found a 5.3% growth rate per year to be approximate to your projections for a colonial world. Your developed worlds may reach equilibrium at 10 billion, but with FTL as easy as you've outlined it, it is reasonable that they will be sending part of their excess to undeveloped worlds post colonization to escape overcrowding.  Let's assume this rate is 10,000/yr/colony.  Also, as time goes on, you'll be getting more and better starships; so, let's say for each new cycle of colonization, we double your immigration rates per colony thanks to advancements in technology. Your cycles of expansion then take the following time frames to reach 5 billion people before opening up new worlds .

- 1st cycle: 15 billion people on 2 worlds after 195 yrs. = 195yrs
- 2nd cycle: 30 billion people on 4 worlds after another 182 yrs. = 377yrs
- 3rd cycle: 60 billion people on 8 worlds after another 169 yrs. = 548yrs
- 4th cycle: 120 billion people on 16 worlds after another 156 yrs. = 702yrs
- 5th cycle: 240 billion people on 32 worlds after another 143 yrs. = 845yrs
- 6th cycle: 480 billion people on 64 worlds after another 129 yrs. = 974yrs
- 7th cycle: 940 billion people on 128 worlds after another 116 yrs. = 1090yrs

At these rates, after ~1090 years you will have 64 planets with ~10 billion people and 64 planets with ~5 billion people. Resulting in ~960 billion people.  But there is another factor at play here which is that this calculation is just how many people you will have up to the point that they are done having babies.  You'll still have a whole population of older people that this equation does not account for; so, to adjust for this, your real trillion person mark will probably hit at ~1050-1070 years after the first colony depending on average life expectancies.

That said, my immigration rates are also pretty speculative here depending on just how fast people immigrate.  Based on various models of expansion, you could be looking at anywhere from ~1780 years (for no immigration beyond seed colonies) to as little as ~135 years if each planet could maintain an infinite emigration potential and optimal population growth rate of 5.3%.

In the end, you actually have a lot of freedom when defining a "reasonable" time lapse for people to hit these populations since a minor variation in reproduction, a single invention, or a single war could push this outcome in either direction by centuries.

Comment: Thank you for providing such a thorough answer to my question.  I your answer of around 1090-1780 years feels right in my gut.  You might also be interested in the answers given to the same question I asked on the mathematics stack exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266588/the-minimum-timescales-to-reach-a-population-of-1-trillion-people

Comment: @Brythan In this context, I meant "immigration", not "emigration" since I was mathematically concerned about the implications of the people going into the colonies, not leaving the developed worlds.  The developed worlds can replace loses much faster than they export colonists.

Comment: @Jimmery Thanks, one thing I'd like to point out is that while this estimate is based on your stipulations, the stipulations are pretty conservative. With such fast travel, people would likely colonize and emigrate much faster than this. If I were you, I'd consider adding strong limiting factors to colonization like making spaceship fuel REALLY expensive to process and making terraforming a requirement for every new planet so that we don't just go out and make 1000s of colonies.

Comment: Also, it's unrealistic to expect planets to all level out at an average of 10 billion.  With enough advances in technology, it's estimated that Earth alone could sustain 1 trillion people; so, it might be better to adopt a model that slows down to a very slow growth past 10 billion rather than a complete end to population expansion. If you think of it like this, if the whole Earth had China's population density, then the world would have a population of about 63.7 billion, and China is still growing at 0.6%/yr; so, 300-600 years might be more realistic.

Comment: @Nosajimiki  But then "for no immigration beyond seed colonies" makes no sense.  You can't immigrate beyond, only within.  At best, you should be using a mix of emigration and immigration, because sometimes you are talking about leaving (emigrating).  You also change immigrate to immigration in one place.